# send event to another google analytics from tag manager - Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to send events to third-party google analytics from google tag manager. Lets say Android logged event, tag manager checks for certain conditions and send that event to specific google analytics property (which is of client)
Any solution will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to know that mobile GTM is pretty limited. In fact, it's so limited that it's quickly becoming an industry practice not to use it. It adds more complication to the architecture than it solves.

Now to your question: you can send an event to another analytics property if it's Universal Analytics. GTM won't let you do that with Firebase due to the limitations of the Firebase SDK. It was never meant to be able to work with multiple instances of Firebase.

If you really need it, you still can send data directly to GA4 through its [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4). But that would be a completely different scope.

Comment: Yes, GTM for android yet to support GA4. We are currently trying to achive above requirement by involving 2 GTM, one for Android and 2nd for web. Android one will fire image link tag with query parameters which we required and hitting on that link web GTM will do the rest. Still in POC state but finger-crossed.

Comment: Wow. That's harsh. No, I would never suggest doing that. GTM for android doesn't have to support GA4 because Firebase effectively is the same thing as GA4 protocol- and data structure-wise. And it's very ez to move the data from FB to GA4. For now, the industry best practice is to implement normal Firebase tracking with no GTM involvement and then just link FB to GA4: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en

Comment: God no, by just moving the data like that from Android to GA4 through a web GTM mirror you're losing A LOT of dimensions and native Firebase events. You really don't wanna do it. Reimplementing it from scratch would be a huge pain. It would be much better to spend that effort to then later ETL the data from GA4 to BQ, and then from there to somewhere like Snowflake and move your analysts and data stakeholders to something like Looker, PowerBI, Tableau. To a good BI tool rather than struggling with Google Data Studio or GA4's explorer.

Comment: Also, web GTM would need a client to execute. It can't just listen to requests without the client. Unless you mean the server side GTM. But even with the server-side gtm. You would need to make up a client id and a session id for it and maintain them on your own, I guess? since you'd be bypassing firebase sdk alltogether. At this point, you're rebuilding your data framework. Why use google at all. If you rebuild it, use something better. Use Segment or something advanced like that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question. The point of GTM is that you are able to use multiple Analytics IDs and send data to them based on custom events.

For example, if you want to send purchase events to GA4-1, and add_to_cart events to GA4-2, you can do that.

Comment: Yes, It can send but problem is as stated by @BNazaruk Android GTM only has Universal Analytics and not GA4. which makes it difficult.